# Tomcat 10 and quartz

Tags: java, tomcat, version, quartz

Hi all: today we are running Tomcat 9.0.5 and quartz 2.3. We would like to migrate to Tomcat 10 but quartz 2.3 breaks. Do you know if quartz 2.4 is ok with Tomcat 10?
Thanks
Pietro

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 10.0 is a Jakarta Servlet 5.0 container. This basically means that it uses the new `jakarta.servlet.*` packages instead of `javax.servlet.*`, while it has [very few improvements](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/changelog.html) on the 9.0 version.

On the other hand it is binary incompatible with all libraries relying on Java EE Servlet up to 4.0, which is the vast majority of libraries.

Quartz is no exception: even the `master` git branch still uses `javax.servlet`, so the official release will not work on Tomcat 10.0. You can however branch the code, change (almost) all `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` in classes [such as this](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerListener.java) and recompile.

Personally I don't see any advantage in migrating to Tomcat 10.0, which implies either dropping support for Tomcat 9.0, maintaining two versions of web applications or using some `ClassTransformer` tricks.

**Edit:** Quartz seems to have started the Jakartification process (cf. [PR #913](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/pull/913)), but hasn't released it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not to difficult to solve, all we did was refactor and reimplement the QuartzInitializerListener.java and QuartzInitializerServlet.java classes found inside the org.quartz.ee.servlet package, reflecting the jakarta.servlet.* namespaces. Instead of using the quartz implementation, just implement or extend yours.

ie:

```
@WebListener
public class QuartzContextListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Scheduler are started in web.xml parm FILE
        super.contextInitialized(sce);
        
        // Get Access to the Factory
        ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);        

        // Register the Listeners implemented by this Class
        //addListeners();
        
        // Default State
        //SchedulerState = SchedulerStateEnum.SHUTDOWN;
        
        // Start the Scheduler
        startScheduler();
        
    } //contextInitialized
    
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // De-Register the Listeners implemented by this Class 
        //removeListeners();
        
        // Destroy Last - Order of Operation
    super.contextDestroyed(sce);
    } //contextDestroyed

    public static void startScheduler() {
        try {
            if( getScheduler().isShutdown() || getScheduler().isInStandbyMode() ) {
                getScheduler().start();
            }
        } catch(SchedulerException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```